# Cache and memory

Tags: memory, mips

First of all, this is not language tag spam, but this question not specific to one language in particulary and I think that this stackexchange site is the most appropriated for my question.

I'm working on cache and memory, trying to understand how it works.
What I don't understand is this sentence (in bold, not in the picture) :

> In the MIPS architecture, since words are aligned to multiples of four
>   bytes, **the least significant two bits are ignored** when selecting a
>   word in the block.

So let's say I have this two adresses :

```
    [1........0]10
    [1........0]00
         ^
         |
   same 30 bits for boths [31-12] for the tag and [11-2] for the index (see figure below)
```

As I understand the first one will result in a MISS (I assume that the initial cache is empty). So one slot in the cache will be filled with the data located in this memory adress.

Now, we took the second one, since it has the same 30 bits, it will result in a HIT in the cache because we access the same slot (because of the same 10 bits) and the 20 bits of the adress are equals to the 20 bits stored in the Tag field.

So in result, we'll have the data located at the memory `[1........0]10` and not `[1........0]00` which is wrong !

So I assume this has to do with the sentence I quote above. Can anyone explain me why my reasoning is wrong ?

The cache in figure :

[image]

Comment: Are you doing a one byte or a one word access?

Comment: You're ignoring "when selecting a word in the block". The last to bits aren't *always* ignored, just when determining what needs to be cached. The actual memory access uses the full address.

Comment: @PeterLawrey If it's one word I understand this will lead to the same, I shouldn't care about the byte offset. Right ?

Comment: @KerrekSB So the last two bits are ignored when I'll do a `lw` for example and there will be a multiplexer with the byte offset as control signal when I'll use `lb` to get the correct byte ?

Comment: The last two bits will be used when the block size is more than one word. So using those two bits you will find offset within the cache entry.

Comment: When you read 4 words from xxxx010 you are actually reading xxxxx011, xxxxx100, xxxxx101 as well, so this means you are actually touching two words and this can mean two reads and even two MISSes of the cache.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think I understood correctly. Does my answer makes sense ? I think this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the MIPS architecture, since words are aligned to multiples of four
>   bytes, the least significant two bits are ignored when selecting a
>   word in the block.

It just mean that in memory, my words are aligned like that :

[image]

So when selecting a word, I shouldn't care about the two last bits, because I'll load a word.

This two last bits will be useful for the processor when a load byte (`lb`) instruction will be performed, to correctly shift the data to get the one at the correct byte position.